# Regular expression Named Capture Group alternatives with leading $ character

Tags: python, regex

I have two groups web and var, with the following alternative strings: aliceblue, yellow and $aliceblue, $yellow

I am able to get matches for aliceblue and yellow in group web but i am not getting matches for $aliceblue or $yellow in group var.

```
re = '/(?x)(?i)(?<![@#$.\-_])(?:\b(?P<var>$aliceblue|$yellow)\b(?!\()|\b(?P<web>aliceblue|yellow)\b(?!\())(?![@#$.\-_])/m';
str = 'aliceblue';
```

I tried to escape the $ character without success

```
re = '/(?x)(?i)(?<![@#$.\-_])(?:\b(?P<var>\$aliceblue|\$yellow)\b(?!\()|\b(?P<web>aliceblue|yellow)\b(?!\())(?![@#$.\-_])/m';
str = '$aliceblue';
```

How can I change the regex so I get a match for $aliceblue in group var and aliceblue in group web?

Comment: Per rules laid out in [tag:regex] tag, please also tag with the host language/environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides escaping the `$` in your regex, you also need to get rid of `\b` just before it, as `$` is not part of word character `\w` which is [a-zA-Z0-9_]

[Check this demo with \b removed from your regex](https://regex101.com/r/I093jy/1)

Comment: Well what can I say - Thank you!